# M1 - Persistent grid filters?

Tags: php, magento-1, grid, product-grid

I've noticed our grids have filters applied whenever going onto Manage Products, if I reset filter and refresh the page the filter is reapplied

Checked the logs and couldn't find any errors...

Comment: Are you using admin id with someone else? It makes it seem like resetting filter doesn't work but someone else using admin id remain that filter or session kept in another computer, it appears !

Comment: Well we've got about 10 people all logged in simultaneously, can't see any errors relating to this and recently moved to redis which should of cleared sessions and still having this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I set "Filters" to Force Original Value in the base configuration of the custom grids extension which fixed my issue